# Accessing static html file within Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have set up `mvc:resources` in my mvc--dispatcher-servlet.xml as below

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="resources/images/favicon.ico" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/maintenance" location="resources/html/maintenance.html" />
```

So far it only works for the first two location (resource mappings). I can only access the static html by supplying the full URI

`http://mydomain/resources/html/maintenance.html`

instead of

`http://mydomain/maintenance`

**UPDATED**

I added `<http pattern="/maintenance" security="none" />` in my spring-security-context.xml  and it gives me new error, *HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available.*

What did I miss here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the issue is caused by this

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The easy way out for me was to change the maintenance URI to `/maintenance.html`, thus the request is not 'handled' by the servlet.

If there's anyone can point out a better solution which allows me to access it as `/maintenance`, I'll accept that as the answer.